# How to save date correctly in Angular 5 app?

Tags: angular, typescript, date

I have the following class in Angular:

```
export class Company {
  id : number;  
  myDate: Date;  
}
```

In the template I have string:

```
<input type="text" "datepicker" name="dateStr" #dateStr="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="dateStr">
```

The dateStr is typestring:

```
 private dateStr: string;
```

When loading the page I have the following code (working fine):

```
let date = new Date(this.company.founded);        
let dateStrMonth = date.getMonth() + 1;
let dateStrDay = date.getDate();        
let dateStrYear = date.getFullYear();
this.dateStr = dateStrMonth + "/" + dateStrDay + "/" + dateStrYear ;
```

When saving the company I currently have the following parsing:

```
saveCompany(compFormDirective:FormGroupDirective) {     
     if (this.dateStr != null) {       
      this.company.myDate = new Date(this.dateStr);
     }
     ...
    }
```

The date is actually saved to the java and mysql but the day is appear with day minus 1. For example if I have 1/7/2002 what being saved is 1/6/2002.
Any idea what should I change/add in the code to make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: what are u getting when u do `console.log(this.dateStr)` ?

Comment: console.log(this.dateStr) nothing is being displayed.

Comment: what value this property has `this.company.founded`. console.log it and share us

Answer (score 1):

Date constructor takes date string in the following format. So in your case you are passing dateStr wrong format.

```
new (year: number, month: number, date?: number)
```

So you need to pass dateStr to the following `getDate` method to get proper date object

```
saveCompany(compFormDirective:FormGroupDirective) {     
     if (this.dateStr != null) {       
      this.company.myDate = this.getDate(this.dateStr);
     }
     ...
    }

getDate(dateStr :string): Date {
        // console.log(dateStr)
        if (dateStr !== undefined) {
            var dateParts = date.split("/");
            // console.log(dateParts)
            return new Date(dateParts[2], dateParts[0] - 1, dateParts[1]); // month is 0-based
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a built-in from Angular in relevance to Date manipulation without having to do all the actual work. Use [Angular Date Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) and its [Built-in Format Options](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#pre-defined-format-options)

Had also provided a [Stackblitz Demo Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-component-date-pipe) for your reference which you can play with other Date Formats as well.

```
@Component({
  ...,
  providers: [ DatePipe ]     // Add DatePipe from @angular/common
})
export class SampleComponent implement OnInit {

   dateStr: any;

   constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

   ngOnInit() {
     ...

     const companyFoundedDate = new Date(this.company.founded); 

     // So date will be in format of 03/09/2019
     this.dateStr = this.datePipe.transform(companyFoundedDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy');
   }

   saveCompany(compFormDirective: FormGroupDirective) { 
      // this.dateStr is already of Date type, you can also console it to check its value
      if (this.dateStr) this.company.myDate = this.dateStr;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use custom controller you can you format MM/dd/yyyy and handle again in back-end java. If you use rest repository you can use as below:

```
        List<aaa> searchByAgentAndEffectiveTimeBetween(@Param("agentId")Long agentId,@Param("startDate") Date startDate, @Param("endDate") Date endDate);
```

Or:

```
@ApiOperation("find XXX history filter effectDate")
@RestResource(path = "filterBetweenTime")
@Query("SELECT f FROM XXX f"
        + " WHERE (:fromDate = NULL AND :toDate = NULL)"
            + " OR (:fromDate = NULL AND f.effectiveDate <= :toDate)"
            + " OR (:toDate = NULL AND f.effectiveDate >= :fromDate)"
            + " OR (f.effectiveDate <= :toDate AND f.effectiveDate >= :fromDate))")
Page<XXX> filterXXXXRecordsBetweenTime(@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")@Param("fromDate") Date fromDate, 
                                                        @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")@Param("toDate") Date toDate, 
                                                        Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem I had to parse to string each value when loading the page:
Changed this:

```
this.dateStr = dateStrMonth + "/" + dateStrDay + "/" + dateStrYear ;
```

To this:

```
this.dateStr = dateStrMonth.toString() + "\/" + dateStrDay.toString() + "\/" + dateStrYear.toString() ;
```